# Building my create-react-app with electron-builder fails

Tags: electron, create-react-app

Decided to build my create-react-app app with electron.
[This is the tutorial I followed](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3) but for my project.

Everything seems to work, except actually opening the application which is getting a segmentation fault.

[Repo Link](https://github.com/charbelsako/pomodoro-timer)

I am also getting this error when installing the app with `dpkg`

> chmod: cannot access '/opt/pomodoro timer/chrome-sandbox': No such file or directory

If you need more information, ask me.

The app gets built with `electron-builder` but I can't open it.
Why is this happening? and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the version of electron used to `5.0.6` 
and then modified the command that runs the app (in the `.desktop` file) to include `--no-sandbox`